# How to configure Dotnet-DEB packager to create folders, change permissions, and etc?

Tags: .net, linux, ubuntu, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

The most common way to distribute Linux Packages is via DEB File. For dotnet core, one can create packages via dotnet-DEB.

https://github.com/qmfrederik/dotnet-packaging

How do I add commands in the DEB Package so that when a user install the package via dpkg command, it performs tasks like

- Creating folders?
- Changing Folder Permssions?
- Adding and starting services?